# Need Strongly-Named version of DotNetNuke (DNN); do I need to recompile source files due to internal references?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, dotnetnuke

I am in the process of Strongly Naming a system which uses DotNetNuke (DNN). Our own assemblies are now signed with a key file from within VS2013 and I have used the ildasm/ilasm method of strongly naming the DNN dlls with the same key file to keep things simple for now. But I am still seeing errors like

```
The type 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'DotNetNuke, Version=7.2.0.607, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

which suggests ('PublicKeyToken=null') that some reference to DotNetNuke dll is not looking at the new, strongly named version. I'm sure I've updated all references within our code so I'm wondering whether this due to an internal reference within the DNN code itself. In that case do I need to recompile the DNN source with references changed to the Strongly Named assemblies?

If you have deployed a DNN site using strongly-named dlls please let me know what you had to do to make it work, thanks a lot.

Comment: That error shows you what it tells. You need to add a reference to the DotNetNuke assembly. Maybe now it's a different assembly after you put the sign into it?

Comment: Sure, but all the references to DNN dlls within VS projects are 100% showing as 'Strong Name = True' which contradicts with the 'PublicKeyToken = null' in the error statement.

Comment: Once I had a problem with strong names and I needed to disassembly and resign it. Maybe it's not the best solution but may it works for you too. Take a look here. If it works I will post it as an answer. 

http://erjjones.github.io/blog/How-to-sign-third-party-assemblies/

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I have already done with all the DNN dlls. Still, *somewhere* there is a reference that needs updating but I know it isn't in one of our own csproj files.

Comment: If it is that the required assembly is needed by one of your referenced assemblies you should be able to solve the issue by just referencing it so that the correct version of this assembly is loaded and can be used.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the issue you are experiencing is that there is a module, or other extension that has a reference to DotNetNuke that doesn't tie to the strong name.

If you want to fully switch to a strong name setup, you will need to 100% change ALL modules and their references.  It is a pretty big ordeal if you are going to handle it.